# What is the difference between pointer to pointer and a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between `temp2` and `temp3` they both point to head

```
node* temp2 = head;
node** temp3 = &head;
```

Comment: I dont think both will point to head.. temp2 will point to head whereas temp3 will point to a pointer that points to head.. to access data in head you can do either temp2->data or (*temp3)->data..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **What is the difference between pointer to pointer and a pointer**

Actually both pointers are the same: A memory position stored in memory. They only differ in what is stored at the memory position they point to.

### Memory, addresses and pointers

You can think of computer memory from a programmer view as a list of pairs:

- Addresses
- Values

Each named object/variable `name` corresponds to

- a certain value (accessed via `name`)
- at a specific memory address (accessed via `&name`)

and therefore one of the memory value/address pairs.

**Example**

Let's assume (for simplicity) that `node` is an integral type. If we define `head` with the value `631`:

```
node head = 631;
```

A certain memory position (i.e. `0x002`) will be chosen (the compiler will choose an offset and the OS will dictate the final position in memory) and the value `631` will be stored at that position.

```
----------------------------------
|   Addr.    |    Val   |  Name  |
----------------------------------
|   0x002    |    631   |  head  |
----------------------------------
```

`head` is now (and only) an alias or name for the value at a specific memory position (`0x002` in this example).

If we define a pointer, there is *nothing* different happening.

```
node* temp2 = &head; // &head == 0x002
```

Again a memory position is chosen  (i.e. `0x005`) and the value (`0x002`) is stored in that position.

```
----------------------------------
|   Addr.    |    Val   |  Name  |
----------------------------------
|   0x005    |   0x002  |  temp2 |
----------------------------------
```

And again the variable name `temp2` is only an alias for whatever value is stored in `0x005`.

The same goes for `temp3` again.

```
node** temp3 = &temp2; // &temp2 == 0x002
```

And the corresponding address/value pair:

```
----------------------------------
|   Addr.    |    Val   |  Name  |
----------------------------------
|   0x007    |   0x005  |  temp3 |
----------------------------------
```

The memory layout of this code

```
node head = 631;
node* temp2 = &head;
node** temp3 = &temp2;
```

looks like this for the present example:

[image]

### Address-of and dereferencing

To turn this into a half-way comprehensive answer with respect to pointers, let's have a quick look at `&` and `*`.

As I already wrote, each `Name` stands for a value/address pair.

```
----------------------------------
|   Addr.    |    Val   |  Name  |
----------------------------------
```

If you decide to apply `&` to a certain name, you will get the address of the value/address pair i.e.:

```
&temp3 == 0x007
```

If you apply `*` instead, this is an alias for whatever is stored at the address corresponding to the current value.

`*temp3` means: "*Give me whatever is stored at the address that is stored in the value of `temp3`*"
So we have two steps here:

1. Fetch the address that is stored in the value of `temp3`
2. Give whatever is stored at that address

Remember:

```
----------------------------------
|   Addr.    |    Val   |  Name  |
----------------------------------
|   0x005    |   0x002  |  temp2 |
----------------------------------
|   0x007    |   0x005  |  temp3 |
----------------------------------
```

1. The "*address that is stored in the value of `temp3`*" is `0x005`.
2. "Whatever is stored at the address" `0x005` is `temp2`.

Therefore

```
*temp3 == temp2 // temp2 is the dereferenced value of temp3
```

since

```
temp3 == &temp2 // value of temp3 is address of temp2
```

You see: Dereferencing (`*`) is the quasi-opposite to address-of `&`.

***Note: `*` in a declaration declares a pointer and is not the operator that dereferences an address.***

Comment: +1 Whoaaa!! Where did you get that picture ? nice explanation :)

Comment: Thanks. Since it is actually consistent the example: I just made in in Illustrator. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A pointer stores a memory location of a data structure, for example your list. A pointer to a pointer will store the memory location of the pointer. It would require an extra dereference to get the the head of the list. So no temp2 and temp3 do not both point to head. temp2 points where head points, while temp3 points to the memory location of the head pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Any pointer keeps an **address** of memory and needs mostly 4bytes (in 32bit systems) of memory to keep this address. according to this definition we can define a pointer to pointer as following:

`pointer to pointer` : 4 bytes in memory that keeps **address** of another memory place which it keeps **address** of somewhere else of memory

Now, We can define temp2 and temp3 as following:

`temp2` : A place in memory that keeps **address** of a `node` object. (mostly every address in a 32bit system need 4 bytes memory ), That this address is equivalence to `head` object content.

`temp3` : A place in memory that keeps address of a pointer to `node` object in memory, which this pointer to node can be define as a `node` pointer.
So temp3 keeps address of address of head node, And because of type of `head` variable is **single address** then requires `&` operator that gets address of `head` variable.

Comment: How often are 32 bit systems in use anymore? Hasn't most stuff switched to x86_64? Sure, you see 32 bit in embedded systems and mobile devices, but that's about it, no? Assuming 32 bit is probably not a good thing.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I use 32bit systems in my answer as just an **example**, you can find size of pointers with `sizeof()` in other systems

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
*temp3 = new_head;
```

But

```
*temp2 = new_head;
```

does not work

It is useful for functions e.g.

```
void make_list(Node ** head) {
    *head = malloc(sizeof(Node);
}
```

Comment: But `temp2 = new_head;` does and `temp3 = new_head` does not work. And you're missing a paranthesis `)` in the last snippt.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer is a variable that holds the address of a variable .

We can declare it like :

```
char *a;
```

And then we can assign the address of a variable such as :

```
char b='r';
```

Like this :

```
a=&b;
```

Pointer to a pointer is also a variable which holds the address of a pointer ( the variable that holds the address of any variable ).

We declare it like :

```
char **c;
```

And then we can assign the address of pointer i.e, `a` like this :

```
c=&a;
```

Since `c` contains the address of `a` which contains the address of b we can later dereference it using a `**`

By this simple example you can understand what do those two statements mean. Good luck !!